# Best way to scrape CSVs on the web with Python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I am looking to replace Yahoo Query Language with something more manageable and dependable. Right now we use it to scrape public `CSV` files and use the information in our web app.

Currently I am having trouble trying to find an alternative and it seems that scraping websites with `Python` is the best bet. However I don't even know where to start.

My question is what is needed to scrape a `CSV`, save the data and use it elsewhere in a web application using Python? Do I need a dedicated database or can I save the data a different way?

A simple explanation is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit broad, but let's divide it in separate tasks

> My question is what is needed to scrape a CSV

If you mean downloading CSVs files from already known URLs, you can simply use `urllib`. If you don't have the CSVs URLs you'll have to obtain them somehow. If you want to get the URLs from webpages, `beautifulsoup` is commonly used to parse HTML. `scrapy` is used for larger-scale scraping.

> save the data.
>
> Do I need a dedicated database or can I save the data a different way?

Not at all. You can save the CSV files directly to your disk., store them with `pickle`, serialize them to JSON or use a relational or NoSQL database. What you should use depends heavily on what you want to do and what of access you need to the data (local/remote, centralized/distributed).

> and use it elsewhere in a web application using Python

You'll probably want to learn how to use a web framework for that (`django`, `flask` and `cherrypy` are common choices). If you don't need concurrent write access, any of the storage approaches I mentioned would work with these